# Which is correct? Suggest me the best out of it

Tags: verbs, sentence, verb-agreement

I wish no human will ever get trapped like this.

I wish no human ever get trapped like this.

I wish no human ever gets trapped like this.

Comment: Hello, VRTX. The request 'Suggest me the best out of it' strongly indicates that ELL, our sister site aimed at those attempting to master basic English, is the more appropriate site for you to visit.

Comment: "Suggest me" is not English.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to EL&U. I'm sorry to have to tell you that none of your sentences is in the form that would be used by native English speakers.

The closest one is the third one but it needs the word 'that' to be inserted after 'wish' to give

> I wish *that* no human ever gets trapped like this

Having said that even that isn't right unless the speaker is actually making a wish, that is that the speaker is invoking some magical power. For instance a character in a story might be given a wish by a supernatural being and might say to the being "I wish that no human ever gets trapped like this"

If there is no specific magical wish to be granted the speaker would be expressing a *hope* rather than invoking a wish and would say "I *hope* no human ever gets trapped like this". If the speaker says "wish" then they expecting a supernatural power to protect all humans from the fate described and very few people belive in that sort of power these days. If the speaker says "hope" they expressing a desire for the outcome but are not invoking a power.

We do, sometimes, say "wish" in sentences like this in normal speech but we are expressing a desire for something we know we cannot or are unlikely to obtain. For instance someone trapped at the bottom of a well might say "I wish I had a ten-metre ladder" because they could use the ladder to escape or "I wish I was out of this well" but it is the expression of a desire not the invocation of a magical power. Just saying it does not make it come true.

We would only say "wish" when we were talking about something specific which we would like to be true at the time we were speaking but is not. For instance someone might say "I wish my son was home safe". Their son might come home safe but that would be in the future, the wish (which cannot come true) is that the son is at home with them now. The more realistic *hope* would be expressed as "I hope my son comes home safe".